# node.js http set request parameters

Tags: node.js, http, query-string, http-request-parameters

I have a node.js application and I want to call a REST api by using [`http.request`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback). This is my code:

```
http = require("http");

const options = {
        host: localhost,
        port: 8103,
        path: "/rest/getUser?userId=12345",
        method: "GET"
    };

http.request(options, function(res) {
   res.setEncoding('utf8');
   res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
      resolve(JSON.parse(chunk));
   });
}).end();
```

The above code works fine, but I don't want to include the request parameter `?userId=12345` in the path. The path should be: `/rest/getUser`. How do I set the request parameter with `http.request`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js http 'get' request with query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903476/node-js-http-get-request-with-query-string-parameters)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package, which has more features, instead of built in http client.

```
var request = require('request');

var url = 'http://localhost:8103/rest/getUser/';

var paramsObject = { userId:12345 };

request({url:url, qs:paramsObject}, function(err, response, body) {
  if(err) { console.log(err); return; }
  console.log("Response: " + response.statusCode);
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it gives the response: `You must be authenticated to access this URL.`

Comment: If the service is secured, you need to authenticate, it is clear in response.