# How do I pass in path variables for an API request within Node.js itself?

Tags: node.js, express

So I know that there are different node packages that I could use like request and like even the standard HTTP and HTTPS ones but I do not see how I can pass in route parameters within my requests like I can with Postman.

[I got this so far but I do not know where to put my route parameters.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhPIj.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please do not post code as image. Here is a question about it. Please check the answers to a better experience when asking. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I got your question right. You know that there are packages but you do not want to use them?

anyway, here there is a similar question that you might find useful (if I got your problem right )
[node.js http set request parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49770523/node-js-http-set-request-parameters)

to send the request parameters you can choose to put them in your path by doing:

```
const options = {
    hostname: "localhost", 
    port: 3000, 
    method: "POST", 
    path:"/add?yourParameter=yourParameterValue", 
    headers: {}
}
```

but it is hard coded, so it is not a good way to do it.. You can also think of string literal, here the documentation
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings

Answer (score 0):

You should pass in your parameter by including it in your path.

```
//define your route params as string here
const routeParam = ''
const options = {
  /////// your properties
  path: /add/${routeParam}
}
```

And all route params are passed as string variable. So please make sure parsing it from the server side in case your route param is int.

```
parseInt(passedParam);
```